# Как вставить php код в короткий код Вордпресс?

Tags: php, html

У **Вордресс** есть *функция короткий код* который позволяет выводить работу *php программы на html* страницу.

**Как вставить php код в короткий код Вордпресс?**

Answer (score 1):

```
function название функции, придумайте сами() {
Сдесь вписываем php код или return 'Привет я html';
}
 add_shortcode ('короткий код для вставки в страницу Вордпресс с помощью  квадратных скобок, вот так [код]','название функции ту, что придумали');
```